# Append input key to JSON output response in Spring Boot

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, wrapper

I have post api payload with key as one of parameters

```
{
 [ "key":1,
   "employeeId":1
 ]
}
```

For my output I am able to fetch the employee result through repository, but how could I append this key with the response json

```
{
 [ "key":1,
   "employeeName":"Rahul",
   "deptId": 1,
   "salary": 10000
 ]
}
```

My Employee pojo is a simple Class with only three fields, is there any way I could return key in payload without creating a Wrapper class.

```
@Value
@JsonInclude(NON_NULL)
public class Employee{
    String name;
    Integer deptid;
    Long salary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For you question,

> but how could I append this key with the response json ("key":1)

You can create a JSONObject and put the key value into it, along with the bean value. Something like :-

```
JSONObject result = new JSONObject();
result.put(key_value);
result.put(Employee bean values); // each value you can put.
```

And then return the object.

Comment: I have to basically return a list of employees not just one. I agree I could keep adding a list to JsonObject. But currently we are utilizing JSON autoconversion and the controller returns a List<Employee>